On the definition of abundant divisors
In page 2-Definition 2.1 of this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2108.02332, the definition of abundant divisor is given as follows:
Let $X$ be a normal projective variety and $D$ be a nef $\mathbb{Q}$-divisor with Iitaka dimension $\kappa(X, D)$. The numerical dimension of $D$ is defined as $\nu(X, D)=\max \left\{e \mid D^e \not \equiv 0\right\}$. In general, $\kappa(X, D) \leq \nu(X, D) . D$ is abundant if $\kappa(X, D)=\nu(X, D)$. Examples include big nef divisors, semiample divisors and their pullbacks.
By this definition, the numerical dimension of zero divisor (which is nef) is $+\infty$?  (how to understand the maximum value for an empty?) Amazing!
Questions:

1, Is the above definition of an abundant divisor (or numerical
dimension) reasonable? Does it coincide with the usual one (for
example, the definition on page 184 of Nakayama's well-known book
Zariski-Decomposition and Abundance)?
2, Is the zero divisor abundant? (I always thought so in the past, until I encountered the above definition)


The maximum over an empty set is $-\infty$, which is indeed the Iitaka dimension of the divisor $D=0$.

It should be default that for any divisor $D$, $D^0$ is not numerically trivial. So the numerical dimension of the zero divisor is 0
